# How to join a table to another one depending two date columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which are

T1:

```
UserID    Tier    BeginDate                  EndDate
8278020   1       2019-03-02 18:33:04.893    2019-03-28 10:34:33.837
8278020   2       2019-03-28 10:34:33.837    2019-04-01 16:48:22.107
8278020   3       2019-04-01 16:48:22.107    2019-04-07 21:44:40.060
8278020   4       2019-04-07 21:44:40.060    2019-06-30 23:59:59.999
```

T2:

```
UserID     GiftCardID    UseDate       OrderID     IsUsed
8278020    165491838     2019-03-06    23057796    1
8278020    165491839     2019-03-10    23106429    1
8278020    165491840     2019-03-24    23277217    1
8278020    166418161     NULL          NULL        0
8278020    166418162     NULL          NULL        0
8278020    167026357     2019-04-22    23594414    1
8278020    167026358     2019-04-28    23668492    1
```

I want to match two tables such that I show the each tier of the customer when he/she used the giftcard.

For example, when the user used the Giftcard with  '165491839' he was in tier 1.

Or at GiftCardID = '167026357' the tier is 4.

I couldn't find how to match the tables according to that.

I wait for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `JOIN`:

```
select t2.*, t1.tier
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.userid = t1.userid and
        t2.usedate >= t1.begindate and
        t2.userdate < t1.enddate;
```

This is a `left join`, so you won't lose rows if, for some reason, the dates don't match.